# I am trying to change my url with .htaccess, but getting some problems

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my URL after clicking the menu

http://mywebsite.com/page/english-lession/learn-about-influential-people

After that on the same page i have another menu for sorting. when i click on it, it is adding like &mode=advanced in url.

I have added mode variable in the last
http://mywebsite.com/page/english-lession/learn-about-influential-people&mode=advanced

This is my code:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /page?lang=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /page\?lang=(.*)&id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /page/%2/%3\? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /page\?lang=(.*)&id=(.*)&mode=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /page/%2/%3/%4\? [R,L]


</IfModule>
```

Please give me solution where i am wrong

Comment: The query string starts with a question mark, not an ampersand. (If that’s not your  issue, then please go read [ask] first, and then edit your question accordingly. We have no way of knowing what _“it show wrong and not fetching”_ is actually supposed to mean.)

Comment: &mode=advanced at second url

Comment: Do you _want_ this to be part of the _path_ component of the URL, or is this supposed to be a query string? If the latter, then you need to use the _right_ character to start it.

Comment: i have write my code with the problem. if you know the solution then help instead of improving my sentence.

Comment: I can’t do that, if you do not at least manage to answer what I am asking _you_. AGAIN: Is this supposed to be a query string parameter? Then the whole thing needs to start with a question mark, not an ampersand.

Comment: yes it is query string. I am using it in the query.

Comment: talking about this page/%2/%3/%4\  ?

Comment: No, talking about this: `http://mywebsite.com/page/english-lession/learn-about-influential-people&mode=advanced`

Comment: when i click on my menu url is http://mywebsite.com/page?lang=english-lession&id=learn-about-influential-people

.htaccess change it to http://mywebsite.com/page/english-lession/learn-about-influential-people

Comment: Then you should change what your menu items link to first of all - those links should point to the “nice” URLs to begin with, otherwise you are requiring an external redirect first on every single link click.